# String replace is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like :

```
var bag_overweight_bag = "More Than 23 kg (50 lbs.), but not exceeding 45 kg (100 lbs.) - $50 - $59 USD/CAD";
```

Here i need to replace GBP instead of CAD.
My code is :

```
var baggage_currency = "GBP";
bag_overweight_bag = bag_overweight_bag.replace(/CAD/g, baggage_currency);
```

The above code is not working but if i give replace code like below it is working

```
bag_overweight_bag = bag_overweight_bag.replace(/CAD/g, 'GBP');
```

So what is the problem in this?

Comment: It is working fine.

Comment: *the above code* certainly does work

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jyx9yhw1/

Comment: I've tried also on Chrome console and all is working fine.

Comment: do you get any console errors perhaps?

Comment: It works well :D
maybe you have another error , earlier in your code so this one is not executed

Comment: No If i use bag_overweight_bag.replace(/CAD/g, baggage_currency) this , it is not working

Comment: its working on chrome console, what browser are you using?

Comment: empty space replace if i use that like my result is More Than 23 kg (50 lbs.), but not exceeding 45 kg (100 lbs.) - $50 - $59 USD/

Comment: define "not working" ... you say you have `a string like` - is it like that, or EXACTLY that? your code works 100% - please show example that does not work

Comment: As an aside, "$59 USD/GBP" doesn't make sense.

Comment: so am I - please show an example of running code that illustrates the "not working" problem

Comment: is there any error in your developer tools console?

Answer (score 0):

> Code snippet is working fine, make Sure you are not overriding baggage_currency anywhere within performing replace

Answer (score -1):

> This is your code. I have replaced bag_overweight_bag with
>   overweight_bag.

```js
var overweight_bag = "More Than 23 kg (50 lbs.), but not exceeding 45 kg (100 lbs.) - $50 - $59 USD/CAD";

var baggage_currency = "GBP"; 

var bag_overweight_bag1 = overweight_bag.replace(/CAD/g, baggage_currency);


console.log(bag_overweight_bag1)
```

Comment: your "answer" is not an answer, as there is no problem with the original code

Comment: There was a variable error in the original post prior modification. Thats what I Changed. I Showed the code and wants to know where is the issue. It doesn't matter someone mark it an answer or not but code should be working and we need to display it to the seeker

Comment: `There was a variable error in the original post prior modification.` - just looked, no there wasn't

Comment: there was no variable errors - just formatting was changed